# How do I use CMAKE for a custom compiler and custom OS?

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to use CMAKE for a project that is very big, written in C++. But this project is not using a "modern compiler" nor a popular compiler, and is for a *unique* OS that, for practical purposes, let say I made it so I have access to almost all of its source code (but I can't modify it, I only have *modify* access to my project). Lets call this OS, OSreally.

My project can be compiled Windows and can run in Windows and OSreally.

What I need to do to implement CMAKE for this project? So I can get all of the CMAKE "benefits".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps I need to do to use CMake with a custom compiler and custom OS is create a new CMake Toolchain configuration file. We can treat our custom OS as a embedded system.

After configuring all the options in the Toolchain file, CMake should work with a custom compiler/OS.

Comment: This is not quite complete, because there's no documentation about how to do the most basic of things, such as how to teach cmake about what to put on the command line for the compiler - especially when the compiler has a completely nonstandard way of doing it. So I imagine your compiler already pretends to act like another compiler. Now imagine you got something that has a command line without any equivalent in anything cmake ever saw before. It turns out you either have to edit cmake sources, or write a cmake script that emulates a more gcc-like command line. :(

Answer (score 2):

In a sense, your question isn't terribly hard to answer. CMake is extremely extensible, and almost everything can be changed. For example, to use your custom compiler, you could `SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /path/to/compiler)` in your top level build file. However, even though a few more hacks like this will get you on your way to *compiling* code for your strange OS, there may also be issues with various system functions and the standard library.

If no one has implemented the standard library on your OS, you may need to spend some time building it and possibly modifying it to fit with whatever is different on the system. The same goes for basically any library you would want to import. Regardless, if you have a conforming C++ compiler for the system, the proper path would be to simply set the above variable in your `CMakeLists.txt` and fix any problems that arise as you encounter them.

Comment: Compiling code for OSreally with CMake is not so hard, but CMake is adding a lot of undesirable flags for the compiler, my compiler ignores the unknown parameters and only takes the valid ones so it compiles fine.

Linking is the part CMake is not doing anything I say it to do it, it doesn't want CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS, cmake_c_link_executable nor other options that I found in Google, I can modify the default values of the language linking of CMake so it links, but it also doesn't found the right directories.

So I want to start from zero, like I was making a new compiler.

Comment: Also, we don't use C++ standard library in OSreally, but we do have the C standard library implemented.

Our compiler is C++98 compliant.

Comment: Linking in C-languages is tedious, certainly. Without knowing anything more, I'd guess that you're passing the correct linker flags, but failing to put the libraries to be linked in the library path. Perhaps investigate https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html to see if that setting could help?